# React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, react-hooks

I am trying to write an error handler, but I get this error:
React Hook "useHttpErrorHandler" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function
I don't how else can I handle this errorHandler.

this is withErrorHandler :

```
    const WithErrorHandler = (WrappedComponent, axios) => {
        return props => {
            const [error, clearError] = useHttpErrorHandler(axios);
            return (
                <div>
                    <ErrorModal show={error} errorModalClosed={clearError}>
                        {error ? error.message : null}
                    </ErrorModal>
                    <WrappedComponent {...props}/>
                </div>
            )
        }
    };
    
    export default WithErrorHandler;
```

and this is http-error-handler:

```
export default httpClient => {
    const [error, setError] = useState(null);

    const reqInterceptor = httpClient.interceptors.request.use(req => {
        setError(null);
        return req;
    });
    const resInterceptor = httpClient.interceptors.response.use(
        res => res,
        err => {
            setError(err);
        }
    );
    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            httpClient.interceptors.request.eject(reqInterceptor);
            httpClient.interceptors.response.eject(resInterceptor);
        };
    }, [reqInterceptor, resInterceptor])
    const errorConfirmHandler = () => {
        setError(null);
    };

    return [error, errorConfirmHandler]
}
```

Comment: The issue is probably how `WithErrorHandler` is used and how the resulting component is called.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon the same error message when I was using a hook in a useEffect. Might be a bit unrelated to the OP question, but I'm pretty sure you will come here when you google the error message.

So, what you can do is use a ref to your hook function.

```
  const { hookFunction } = useMyHook();
  const hookFunctionRef = useRef(hookFunction);
```

Then use the hookFunctionRef.current() in your useEffect and the hookFunctionRef in your useEffect dependency array.

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled upon same problem for what solved it, is to put your use effect within the main function where the return is called but not within the return it self nor outside the main function.

```
    function Navbar() {
    useEffect(() => {........}
    return ()
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

You cannot use the hook within a return statement, try below, keeping the hook outside of return:

```
  const WithErrorHandler = (WrappedComponent, axios) => {
    const [error, clearError] = useHttpErrorHandler(axios);
    return props => {
      return (
        <div>
          <ErrorModal show={error} errorModalClosed={clearError}>
            {error ? error.message : null}
          </ErrorModal>
          <WrappedComponent {...props} />
        </div>
      );
    };
  };
```

Comment: I tried this. but this error happens : Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See  l for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Comment: would it be possible for you give a link to a Code sandbox, with your code.

Comment: Hooks need to be inside a React component. The above works as long as function is defined inside the React context.