# How to implement caching in react-firebase-hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have been trying to implement caching in [react-firebase-hooks](https://github.com/csfrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/1d1ca28241ece8f4662aa2aeadff132cd880c32b/firestore) but getting this error

> React Hook "useCollectionDataOnce" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function

I know that I am calling it conditionally but is there any other way to do this? By the way, I am following [this](https://www.robinwieruch.de/local-storage-react) to implement caching.

```
const [randomQuestions, setRandomQuestions] = React.useState([]);
const cachedData = localStorage.getItem("randomQuestions");
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (cachedData) {
      setRandomQuestions(JSON.parse(cachedData));
    } else {
      let [values, loading, error] = useCollectionDataOnce(
        db
          .collection("questions")
          .where("tags", "array-contains-any", tags.length ? tags : [""])
          .limit(10),
        { idField: "id" }
      );
    }
    if (values) {
      localStorage.setItem("randomQuestions", JSON.stringify(values));
      setRandomQuestions(values);
    }
  });
```

In the code, I am trying to check if `cachedData` already exists or not. If not, then query and fetch the data. If yes, then set `randomQuestions`.

Answer (score 0):

React Hooks cannot be inside a conditional as stated [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html). You should use it outside the if/else statement.

Looking the [documentation](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/blob/master/firestore/README.md#usecollectiondataonce) of `useCollectionDataOnce` I've found that the variables of the function are optional, so you can define an auxiliar variable that is populated in the if/else statment depending on your needs and it is passed to the `useCollectionDataOnce`.

```js
const [randomQuestions, setRandomQuestions] = React.useState([]);
const cachedData = localStorage.getItem("randomQuestions");
React.useEffect(() => {
    var query = "";
    if (cachedData) {
          setRandomQuestions(JSON.parse(cachedData));
          query = "";
    } else {
          query = db
              .collection("questions")
              .where("tags", "array-contains-any", tags.length ? tags : [""])
              .limit(10),
            { idField: "id" };  
    }
    let [values, loading, error] = useCollectionDataOnce(query); 
    if (values) {
      localStorage.setItem("randomQuestions", JSON.stringify(values));
      setRandomQuestions(values);
    }
  });
```

Comment: The `useCollectionDataOnce` function is from [react-firebase-hooks](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/master/firestore#usecollectiononce). Its not possible for me to change it. Is it?

Comment: My bad, I misread your question and didn't noticed that `useCollectionDataOnce` is already a React Hook. I've updated the answer with a new solution that I think it will help you.

Comment: I think that the `{idField:"id"}` should be inside the `useCollectionDataOnce`hook.

Comment: Well now, I get the following error: `React Hook "useCollectionDataOnce" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function`

Comment: You can't use a hook inside a return statement. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62753803/react-hooks-must-be-called-in-a-react-function-component-or-a-custom-react-hook) for more insight.

Comment: I agree with you @afarre, but then how do I implement caching placing the `useCollectionDataOnce` hook outside the useEffect.